# MSSQL wont accept connection from website on other host

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Iam using SQL server 2000 SP4 and iam running a website on localhost. 
This worked great, i moved to hostgator to run my websites there.
I changed the IP in inc.config.php but i still get an error when i visit my website.

Core-Error: Failed to connect to database!
Error: Please check if MSSQL-service is running and reachable (firewall, etc.).

I added firewall rules for the ports that are needed and also added sqlserv.exe to the firewall to allow this. The service is up because my client can still connect to my local hosted website.

Do i need to enable remote connection from MSSQL 2000 ?

http://webtest.demoniz.com

Comment: are you sure the connections are being made from the same host as the sql server is installed? If they are not, you probably need to authorize external connections.

Comment: Dear SQL.injection, 

I have no idea we are hosting our gameserver and database on a other server then our website. In the past we hosted our website and gameserver and database on 1 machine. Now we use hostgator for our website and i get this error you see above. I have no idea how to authhorize external connections. Can you provide me with some more information ? Google confuses me lol

Comment: If you are hosting the database in a different server, you should make sure the server is configured to accept external connections; it is very likely the default configuration is to reject them. Can you successfully connect with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: From my dedicated server i can login to Enterprise Manager. SQL Server Management Studio comes from version 2005 i believe.